# Blender Compatibility Script?

Tags: blend-files, compatibility

Is there a script which can correct all compatibility breaks, (automatically looks what version of Blender the file was made with and adds whatever necessary to get it look like before)?

*Example*: Let's say normal map strength is now 10 times smaller. For files created prior to 2.67, just multiply the value with 10 after opening in a 2.67+ version, to get the effect the artist really created.

If not, is there a text file listing all those compatibility breaks so that we can understand why, when a file looks weird/wrong?

Comment: The 'compadibility' tag got approved twice.. I will retag with the correct spelling when the system deletes the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not as far as I know of.

Blender can load older files into newer Blender version, taking care of updating settings.

It's possible to write a script that changes the settings of a .blend file of course, but this would most likely be a workaround for problems in Blender's own conversion, so if there is really a bug there, it should be reported.

In other cases changes cant be easily converted since the settings are not 1:1 equivalent, so in those cases you probably have to accept some manual tweaking to get comparable settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ton himself asked for the file (http://www.emirage.org/2013/04/24/free-download-archviz-project-pabellon-barcelona-3d-scene-v1-2-updated/) to be in the official blender site, it would be a shame if an official file is not correctly supported. But how can I know if it's a bug or an impossible conversion ? My math knowledge is not that good, I thought everything has it's inverse, but if it's not the case. Should I take the risk of reporting something that is not a bug or can you compare the file in 2.66 and 2.67b and say if it can get corrected automatically ?

Comment: If your not sure, report a bug, then the maintainer of that area can see if this can be better converted.